# How to confirm Codable protocol in structure that have NSError object?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, codable

I want to save swift structure object in **UserDefaults** for that I need to confirm **Codable protocol**. I am trying this way but getting some errors-:

1) No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSError'

2)No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSError'

How can solve this?

```
import Foundation

struct FailedImage: Codable {

    let url: String
    var downloadAttempt: Int
    var error: NSError

    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey
    {
        case error
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        error = try values.decode(NSError.self, forKey: .error)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(error, forKey: .error)
    }

}
```

Screenshot of code with error 
[image]

Comment: Instead of writing manual code `FailedImage` write `Codable` extension for `NSError` itself. Also add encoded data to the question, to properly parse `NSError` we need to know how it is stored.

Comment: Show your json string

Comment: Why are you using `NSError` in Swift? Use `Error` instead.

Comment: @user28434 I am downloading image using NSURLSession on failure getting NSError object. I want to store same error object as well as some url and downloadAttempt.

Comment: @LeoDabus Not getting this info from json. I am creating this model object

Comment: Even easier just create your own Error and make it conform to Codable

Comment: @DávidPásztor I tried with swift Error class but still getting same error.

Comment: Then you, personally, is responsible for creating proper code for encoding.

Comment: `struct DownloadError: Swift.Error, Codable {
        let code: Int
        let domain: String }`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus if not find anything then will go with your solution.

Comment: @Deepak, what are you trying to find?

Comment: @Deepak Are you trying to store the URLSession Error?

Comment: @LeoDabus yes I want to save Error or NSError object as its. And any better solution.

Comment: The best solution was already provided.

Comment: Just save what you need: localizedDescription, localizedRecoveryOptions, localizedRecoverySuggestion and localizedFailureReason

Comment: Btw why don’t you simply handle the error instead of saving it?

Comment: Best solution is to use NSKeyedArchiver, a little more complicated but very useful for saving. User Defaults should *not* be used for large objects and is best for small things like Booleans or Strings. Like saving this: `var userHasCompletedIntro: Bool = true`